# tangent line to a circle is perpendicular to the radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The center of a circle is the point D(-2,1), and Q(1,-3) is a point on the circle. Find the equation of the line tangent to the circle at the point Q

[image]

EDIT:

The slope of the radius is -4/3 if I didn't make an error in my calculation. Also I am in algebra 2 and this is supposed to be review... I am stumped, I have never seen this before.

Comment: What is true about the tangent to a circle at a point on its circumference and the radius of the circle that goes to that point?  Find the slope of that radius and, in turn, find the slope of the tangent line.  Since you know the tangent point, you have the information you need to write a "point-slope" form equation for the tangent line to $ \ Q \ . $

Comment: The slope of the radius is -4/3 if I didn't make an error in my calculation. According to my teacher I should put this in slope intercept form. Also I am in algebra 2 and this is supposed to be review... I am stumped, I have never seen this before.

Comment: $-4/3$ is fine so far, now the slop of the tangent line is.. ?

Comment: The inverse opposite so 3/4, I understand that part. I don't understand the formula or how to plug in the values.

Comment: The "point-slope" formula comes from a definition of slope, $ \ m \ = \ \frac{y - y_0}{x - x_0} \ , $ which can be re-arranged into the equation for a line with this slope through the point $ \ (x_0, y_0) \ , \ \ y - y_0 \ = \ m \ (x - x_0) \ . $  You have the slope of the tangent line now and you know the coordinates of $ \ Q \ . $  You can then algebraically re-arrange this "point-slope" equation into the "slope-intercept" form, $ \ y \ = \ mx \ + \ b . \ $

Comment: Every time I post (whether to help somebody or get help myself) somebody edits my stuff... and it's all just for points or power, and it is highly annoying. Back off, unless I make a really big mistake or you have something important to add. minor fixes back off.

Comment: J. W. Perry, if you really want to help, explain how semsem got his answer. It was the correct answer, and I need to know how he got it.

Comment: If you want the Point slope form instead of the slope intercept form, it is $$(y-y_1)=m(x-x_1).$$ I tried to show how that is derived in my post. In this case you just plug in $m$, $x$, and $y$ and you have that result. Specifically, $$(y-(-3))=\frac{3}{4}(x-1).$$ This is the point slope form.

Comment: Your answer is great, thank you. One more question, why do you have to plug those values into y sub 1 and x sub 1, why can't you plug them into x and y? EDIT: Also, I have been told it is y sub 1, y sub 2, x sub 1 and x sub 2.

Comment: You literally could plug them into the $x$ and $y$ and then let the other $x_1$ and $y_1$ be the new $x,y$. It would give the same result. Try it.$$(-3-y)=\frac{3}{4}(1-x) \Rightarrow \ldots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the point-slope formula:

$$\left( y-y_1 \right)=m\left( x-x_1 \right).$$

This is nothing more than a consequence of the definition of slope. More specifically,

$$m=\frac{\left( y_2-y_1 \right)}{\left( x_2-x_1 \right)}\Rightarrow \left( y_2-y_1 \right)=m\left( x_2-x_1 \right).$$

If we are in a situation where we already know the slope $m$ and we already know a point $( x,y )$, we can drop one of the points in that last form (the $_2$ in $x_2$ and $y_2$ for example) and write the point-slope formula as above.

Using the point-slope form
$$(y−y_1)=m(x−x_1),$$
 with $m=\frac{3}{4}$, and the point $(1,-3)$ we substitute our given $m$, $x$, and $y$ to get.
$$(y−(−3))=\frac{3}{4}(x−1).$$

If you want to convert this to the slope intercept form then the process is

\begin{align*}
&(y−(−3))=\frac{3}{4}(x−1) \\
 \Rightarrow & y+3=\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{3}{4} \\
\Rightarrow & y=\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{3}{4}-3 \\
\Rightarrow & y=\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{15}{4}.
\end{align*}

Note that I still recommend my original solution where we start with the slope-intercept form. It is much faster (and seems much more sensible to me), although I have noticed a strange reluctance to demonstrate that method directly in the textbook (Bittinger) that I am currently using for my classes.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am going to save this in case I need it later.